# SSRS Data Driven File share account - impersonation error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I am setting up SSRS data driven subscription with windows file share delivery option.

In regular SSRS subscriptions with windows file share delivery there is an option to use file share account credentials - seems that is missing in data driven subscriptions section

So, when I setup data driven subscription I am getting below error (but it works fine with regular subscription)

ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription Failure writing file : An impersonation error occurred using the security context of the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current job doesn't have the Enterprise edition so I haven't worked with data driven in a while. But there are Username and Password fields in the **Delivery Options** section that can be either hard coded or mapped to your query.

[image]

This is from SSRS2016 - YMMV.

Comment: somehow missed the use file share account option. It is in top location for regular subscription

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to take the user that report subscription is running as add that to the execution account on SSRS config and then on the SSRS server also add that user to the local administrator group

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to configure user for file based subscription.

[image: File Share Subscription Options]

If you are going with Windows user credentials, make sure the user has logon permissions and is not locked on the Server running the SSRS Service.

For File Share options as well just make sure that configured user does not have any issue logging in the SSRS Server.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/subscription-settings-and-a-file-share-account-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2016)